Shared Preference not Survive on AndroidTv app
this code for save
if (!videoKind.equals("trialer")) {
            Setting.refresh=true;
            lastSeen();

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(this.getString(R.string.app_name),0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putLong(videoUrl,10);
            editor.commit();
        }

and this for get
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.app_name),0);  

for (SourceModel m:model.getSourceModels()) {

            if (sharedPreferences.getLong(m.getUrl(),-1)!=-1){

                holder.seen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

        }

but it work only you in the activity and when you leave activity this value will clear
